# Search for two strings at once in java

Tags: java, android, string

So on a basic level is there a way to say (maybe using an operator) look for this string OR this one within the same variable declaration. (maybe an array). I've tried operators such as the pipe and & and it doesn't work with a single string variable input. I have also tried putting the strings into an array and using the string value of that array but all to no avail. Thank you

```
Elements names= doc.body().getElementsContainingOwnText("Mr.");
for (Element web2: names) {
    Log.i("names", web2.text());
}
```

I also want to check for "Ms." but do it at the same time because sequence matters in this instance. By the way this is the jsoup SDK 1.8.3.

Comment: You say you're declaring a variable and looking for a `String` from one of two places.  Do you mean to only set the first one that is not null, or what?  A little unclear.  Maybe you could post some code that you've tried?

Comment: show us some of what you've done to show us what you're thinking.

Comment: Ok sorry on phone will do just a moment

Comment: This isn't a chat room--you don't have to tell us why you can't respond instantly.  :)  Nobody expects an immediate response here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `getElementsMatchingOwnText(String regex)`.

So to match `Mr.` or `Ms.` your query will be something like,

```
Elements names= doc.body().getElementsMatchingOwnText("Mr\\.|Ms\\."); // Escape . in regex.
```

Comment: This may be a silly question but while you are still probably around: this will check for mr. or ms. right? Because you use the word and.

Comment: It's an `or` actually. It's just plain java regex.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Java8 Stream

```
    String s1 = "111";
    String s2 = "222";
    boolean res = Arrays.asList(s1,s2).stream().anyMatch(s->"333".equals(s));
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax but I have encountered it what is the "s".

Comment: s - is a variable which stream will asssign a reference to a next element. In our case it will try s1 then s2. It can be any name, eg e->"333".equals(e)

Comment: And the "333" what part does that play

Comment: He has the Android tag so Java 8 isn't an option here.

Comment: this is what your are searching for, in this case we are testing if s1 or s2 is "333", you can use any code returning boolean, e.g. matches() or indexOf(s, "xxx") != -1 etc

Comment: 1) this doesn't do what the asker is trying to do, 2) it's actually 50% longer than the non-stream version! I hate it when people go out of their way to use streams...

Comment: as soon as Androind supports Java 8

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any Android programming, but have they even gotten up to Java 7 yet?